# Filtering block elements into two columns

Tags: css, css-float

What I'm asking is probably impossible, but still.

Given a series of block elements, like this:

```
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<div class="toc">...</div>
<p>...</p>
<img class="pic">...</img>
<p>...</p>
<img class="pic">...</img>
```

We want all the .toc and .pic elements to line up in one column at the left, and all the other elements to be in a column to the right. The tops of the first `p` and the top of the first `div` should be level. The `img` should retain their original vertical position. There should be no space left where the `div` and `img` were originally.

Most of this seems to be achievable by setting the `img` to `position:relative; left: -100px` (etc), and the `div.toc` to `position:absolute`.

Here's the problem: The `img` may overlap with the bottom of the `div.toc`. Any solutions? Workarounds?

EDIT Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4CAgn/

Comment: By original vertical position (of `img`); do you mean the vertical order? Why don't you use a `table`? or CSS `float`? How about a fiddle so we can understand the question better?

Comment: Good point. http://jsfiddle.net/4CAgn/ The main problem to solve is the image overlapping the TOC div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, I think [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/mgWmA/) is the best you can get:

```css
div.content { 
    width: 400px; 
    position: relative;
}

div.content p {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 220px;
}

div.toc { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    background: #cc9;
    margin: 1em; 
    width: 180px; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px;
    line-height: 2em;
}

img { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 1em;
    width: 180px; 
    left: 0px;
}
```

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/onury/mgWmA/

**Problems with this:**

- If the text (paragraph) before the TOC is shorter than TOC height;
  the next image (after TOC) will still overlap.
- If any text after an image is shorter than the image's height; that
  image can overlap with the next image in line.

**True Workaround:**

I understand that you want to achieve this with CSS only; but I think a flawless implementation is not possible (since you want to get some disordered content into columns). But if you consider javascript, it is possible bec. (for example) you can manipulate the DOM by detaching then re-attaching the elements in a desired order within generated containers.